# Как реализовать Layout Manager для макета с фиксированым размером и разным количеством изображений?

Tags: android, android-layout, gridlayoutmanager, layoutmanager

Я разрабатываю приложение, где пользователь может создавать заметки. Заметка содержит заголовок, изображения и текст. Заметка имеет несколько изображений, но также может содержать одно изображение или пустое пространство. Пользователь добавляет картинки по одной. Картинки имеют макет контейнера с фиксированой высотой в `200dp`. Я должен добавить неизвестное количество изображений в этот контейнер, где он будет красиво скомбинирован из них без пустого пространства, как на картинке ниже. Как мне такое реализовать?

Создание заметок

[image: Приложение]

Мне нужно реализовать что-то вроде этого

[image: Желаемый результат]

Comment: Вот тут смотрели? https://stackoverflow.com/a/31113461/4829111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения этой задачи я использовал [Flexbox](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) от Google.

Comment: я бы сделал акцент именно на [FlexboxLayoutManager](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout#flexboxlayoutmanager-within-recyclerview)

Answer (score 1):

Скорей всего вам нужен [`StaggeredGridLayoutManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html), который розмещает елементы в шахматном порядке.

Comment: API22 серьезное ограничение